# Security checklist for node.js

Tags: node.js, security, express, mean-stack

I have been looking for a checklist that includes solutions for protecting against csrf, over posting, sql injection, etc.  I have been able to find doc. on some of the items such as csrf using csurf but appear to be striking out on over posting.  Could someone point me in the direction of documentation on protecting against overposting in node.js.  Also, I am trying to lock all of my rest endpoints down to just authenticated users, except for the "/login" endpoint.  I am using the MEAN stack for development and looking into using passport for my authentication framework.

Comment: This can be helpful https://blog.risingstack.com/node-js-security-checklist/